# SSIS Excel destination blank

Tags: excel, ssis

I am debugging an SSIS package that starts with SQL Server data, transforms it, and puts it into an Excel file.  I do this frequently in my work, and have never encountered this issue before:  no rows are written to the Excel file.  I attached a data viewer to the precedence constraint that leads to the Excel destination, and I see hundreds of rows of data flowing to the destination.  When the package finishes executing, I open the Excel file and there is no data!

Comment: Check to see if the excel destination is configured to ignore errors.

Comment: That must have been it.  I set the error configuration to fail the package on error, and data went into the spreadsheet.  Seems strange, since there was no error!  But I have learned to expect strange things from SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that it can take some time (many minutes) from a data flow task  appearing to have successfully completed in debug mode before the write to the Excel file is completed.

I just encountered a similar scenario when executing a data flow task with an Excel output, and found that even though the data flow destination block turned green in the debugger (normally a good indication that everything's finished for other file types, e.g. csv) there was nothing in the Excel file. It was only when I started waiting for this message in the Output window that I could successfully see the results:

```
Information: 0x4004300B at Export data for checking, SSIS.Pipeline: "component "Excel Destination" (5918)" wrote 265488 rows.
```

I guess there's some buffering going on somewhere in the final output stage.

My clue was that when running the package as a whole, everything in the data flow task turned green, but the package flow showed the data flow task as still yellow ("in progress") until it was really finished.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but I was able to find the answer when googling.

As I am using SQL on Windows x64 Platform and my office is x86, 
all you have to do is go to your

project properties in Visual Studio and set the value of *Run64BitRunTime* to **False** [image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today, and just in case I can spare someone else the wasted time, my SQL query had use [database] as the first part of the statement

This prevented any rows being exported

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and it was due to some interim SQL I was performing before the final SELECT.

Adding "SET NOCOUNT ON" as the first line fixed the issue.