# Why isn't my data writing to the excel destination? SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a SSIS package that exports several rows to Excel, usually less than 200 (including the header). When I run it in VS2015 Debug everything turns green.

[image]

I even wait like [this question says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987722/2911241).

[image]

Still, nothing but the header ever gets to the file.

I know it's not much data, but I'm trying to automate it as the data will eventually grow and I don't want to manually run this all the time.

Any ideas? I'm using SQL Server 2012 and wrote this SSIS package with VS2015.

Comment: Are you using the FQDN path for the excel?  I suspect it is happily writing to your Sys32 directory.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I am using a fully qualified path name. That was the first thing I checked. What do you mean writing to Sys32? Where would it write to in there?

Comment: SSIS will sometimes output to Windows\System32 if the target path is not correct. Are you using an excel template that is copied and then filled?  Do you have the same effect if you use a text destination?

Comment: @EricHauenstein I am using a template. I haven't tried using a text file. I'll try that now and see what happens.

Comment: If you are using a template, There is probably a minor difference between the Excel Destination path and the path that the template is copied to.  Is the path defined as a variable?

Comment: @EricHauenstein the paths are both static.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161824/discussion-between-eric-hauenstein-and-mike).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something that occasionally happens with Excel destinations is that hidden formatting will cause the data flow connector to begin writing data at a row other than 1.

If this happens, you'll need to recreate your template from a fresh Excel document, and reconstruct the header as needed.

Comment: was looking for this answer forever, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the buffer size that underlying process uses. I monitored the consumption of C: drive while the SSIS package was writing to the Excel destination, and found that the space was getting full, and as soon the whole space is occupied package ended with success without writing any row to excel destination. Therefore I cleared enough space from my C: drive (around 2 GB) and everything started working fine then.

Also found the following useful [thread](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1669725-391-1.aspx) that might be helpful for someone.